# How can I open popup with IE under Windows CE 5.0?

Tags: javascript, popup, windows-ce

I'm developing a part of my web project for hand terminals and these terminals have Windows CE operating system. I want to open popup in Internet Explorer without toolbar and menubar but it doesn't care and it opens normal ie page. Is there any way to open popup without toolbar and menubar?
By the way it's windows ce 5.0 and hand terminal is motorola wt-4090.

```
window.open('foo.aspx', '_blank',
        'width=' + (screen.availWidth - 50) +
        ', height=' + (screen.availHeight - 50) +
        ', left=0, top=0, resizable=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,location=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no');
```